# I'm trying to change order of tags inside textarea with jquery, but it's not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here's the code:

```js
$('#taas').find('BLOG').append($('BLOG_INFO'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="taas" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
<BLOG>
    <BLOG_INFO>
text1
    </BLOG_INFO>
    <POSTS>
text2
    </POSTS>
</BLOG>
</textarea>
```

The Result that I Expected:
inside of textarea:

```
<BLOG>
        
<POSTS>
text2
</POSTS>
        
<BLOG_INFO>
text1
</BLOG_INFO>
    
</BLOG>
```

Why's it not working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *why's it not working* - because there aren't any "tags" inside the textarea, only text.   You'll need to get the text area's text, parse it, change it, then put the updated version back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var blog = $($('#taas').val());
var bloginfo = blog.find("BLOG_INFO")[0].outerHTML

blog.find("BLOG_INFO").remove()
blog.append(bloginfo)

$('#taas').val(blog[0].outerHTML)
```

Problem is that your `$("#tass")` does not contain any elements but only text, so as freedomn-m says you have to parse it as an object, then change it and paste it back into the element.

**Demo**

```js
var blog = $($('#taas').val());
var bloginfo = blog.find("BLOG_INFO")[0].outerHTML

blog.find("BLOG_INFO").remove()
blog.append(bloginfo)

$('#taas').val(blog[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="taas" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
<BLOG>
    <BLOG_INFO>
text1
    </BLOG_INFO>
    <POSTS>
text2
    </POSTS>
</BLOG>
</textarea>
```

You can also do it a bit more simple:

```
var blog = $($('#taas').val());
var bloginfo = blog.find("BLOG_INFO").insertAfter(blog.find("POSTS"))

$('#taas').val(blog[0].outerHTML)
```

**Demo2**

```js
var blog = $($('#taas').val());
var bloginfo = blog.find("BLOG_INFO").insertAfter(blog.find("POSTS"))

$('#taas').val(blog[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="taas" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
<BLOG>
    <BLOG_INFO>
text1
    </BLOG_INFO>
    <POSTS>
text2
    </POSTS>
</BLOG>
</textarea>
```

Comment: both answers are just fine:)

Answer (score 2):

Note that `$("textarea").val()` will always provide a `string`.  These look like tags/elements in the HTML, but they are the textarea's text/value.   You need to get the textarea value (or text) then parse it with jquery in order to manipulate the tags/elements.

---

Here's what I came up with - the output is lowercase (as HTML tags are lowercase these days) and the format isn't ideal as HTML doesn't need whitespace - you could the pass it into a "pretty-print" to get different output

Parse the text into tags

```
var tags = $("<div/>").html($("#taas").val());
```

then manipulate and put back

```js
var tags = $("<div/>").html($("#taas").val());
tags.find('BLOG').append(tags.find('BLOG_INFO'));
$("#taas").val(tags.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="taas" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
<BLOG>
    <BLOG_INFO>
text1
    </BLOG_INFO>
    <POSTS>
text2
    </POSTS>
</BLOG>
</textarea>
```

---

A quick note on

```
$("<div/>").html($("#taas").val());
//vs 
$($("#taas").val());
```

with `$($("#taas").val())` the root element is `BLOG` so you cant do `blog.find("BLOG")` while `$("<div/>").html($("#taas").val());` gives a root element of `div`.  The final result is output using either `innerHTML`/`.html()` for the first or `.outerHTML` for the second.

Comment: both answers are just fine:)